# Error: 'pow' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;

    cout << "How many rows would you like? " << endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Number| Power 1| Power 2| Power 3| Power 4| Power 5" << endl;

    for (int j=0; j<=x; j++)
    {
        cout << j << "\t" << j << "\t" << pow(j,2) << "\t" << pow(j,3) << 
"\t" << pow(j,4) << "\t" << pow(j,5) << endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

It produces the above error. I'm not sure what is wrong, please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't tag spam.

Comment: Sorry I did not know, I'm new. I'll be sure not to again.

Comment: You need to `#include <cmath>` in your code

Comment: Being "new" is really not an excuse. You knew full well that this question had nothing to do with Java or C.

Comment: I thought it was possible for the same problem to occur in the latter languages.

Answer (score 6):

[`std::pow`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/pow/) is defined in `cmath`, so you need to include `cmath`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>   // <-- include cmath here

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;

    cout << "How many rows would you like? " << endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Number| Power 1| Power 2| Power 3| Power 4| Power 5" << endl;

    for (int j=0; j<=x; j++)
    {
        cout << j << "\t" << j << "\t" << pow(j,2) << "\t" << pow(j,3) << 
"\t" << pow(j,4) << "\t" << pow(j,5) << endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error message tells you, the compiler does not know where to find `pow()`.

When using functions that you did not write yourself, you need to include the appropriate header file. Just like you are including `iostream` for `std::cout` and `std::cin`, you need to include `cmath` for `std::pow`.

Just add `#include <cmath>` to the beginning of your program.

Comment: @Pablo thank you, I have edited. Guess I'm getting too tired^^